# Does every execution of java command start a separate JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Does every execution of java command start a separate JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get a separate VM.

Some class resources can be shared ([class data sharing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/class-data-sharing.html)). This is by default enabled, e.g. it's automatically used when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does start a separate JVM.